# Padding a number in NSString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsstring

I have an int, for example say 45. I want to get NSString from this int padded with 4 zeroes. So the result would be : `@"0045"`. Similar, if the int is 9, I want to get: `@"0009"`.

I know I can count the number of digits, then subtract it from how many zeroes i want padded, and prepend that number to the string, but is there a more elegant way? Thanks.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSLog(@"%04d", 45);
NSLog(@"%04d", 9);
```

If it works, then you can get padded number with

```
NSString *paddedNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%04d", 45];
NSString *otherPaddedNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%04d", 9];
```

**Update**

If you want to have arbitrary number you'd have to create a format for your format:

```
// create "%04d" format string
NSString *paddingFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%0%dd", 4];

// use it for padding numbers
NSString *paddedNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:paddingFormat, 45];
NSString *otherPaddedNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:paddingFormat, 9];
```

**Update 2**

Please see @Ibmurai's comment on how to properly pad a number with NSLog.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. This works perfectly, but how can I specify an arbitrary number? I tried:     NSLog(@"%0%id",4, 45); but this doesn't work. Thanks again.

Comment: It's silly to create a format for your format. Simply use [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0*d", 4, 45]. The *, the length to pad, refers to an argument, too... So 4 "replaces" the star.

Comment: @Ibmurai Now that you showed the shortest answer - it really is silly. My printf-fu is weak .)

Answer (score 20):

Excuse me for answering this question with an already accepted answer, but the answer (in the update) is **not** the best solution.

If you want to have an arbitrary number you **don't** have to create a format for your format, as [IEEE printf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html) supports this. Instead do:

```
NSString *paddedNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0*d", 4, 45];
NSString *otherPaddedNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0*d", 4, 9];
```

While the other solution works, it is less effective and elegant.

From the IEEE printf specification:

> A field width, or precision, or both, may be indicated by an asterisk ( '*' ). In this case an argument of type int supplies the field width or precision.

Answer (score 1):

Swift version as Int extension (one might wanna come up with a better name for that method):

```
extension Int
{
    func zeroPaddedStringValueForFieldWidth(fieldWidth: Int) -> String
    {
        return String(format: "%0*d", fieldWidth, self)
    }
}
```

Examples:

```
print( 45.zeroPaddedStringValueForFieldWidth(4) ) // prints "0045"
print( 9.zeroPaddedStringValueForFieldWidth(4) ) // prints "0009"
```